# websockets and php update?

Tags: php, websocket

I am intrigued and excited by the possibilities of WebSockets with PHP.

I have spent hours Googling and it seems there was a flurry of activity 2012/13 but little since. React warns its product is not ready for mainstream. Ratchet refers to PSR-0 which has been replaced by I think PSR-4, so is not encouraging. And almost nothing current to be found on stackoverflow. A number of other socket based servers on Github seem to have stalled or been abandoned.

I'm not a guru and as such need some detailed information and working solutions. I care not about supporting old browsers.

Is there anything up to date and functional? Or is the concept still too experimental? Or am I somehow missing the obvious?

Comment: I think you are looking something like `RACHET`. chek that once.

Comment: You can take [the specs (RFC-6455)](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6455/?include_text=1) and implement your own client/server using tcp sockets.

Comment: @Dan If I was confident enough I wouldn't be asking here! It seems a number of people did that years ago but I can't find anything active for PHP